# when hooking divs are ngIf'd out i have to use unique html id's on the div, why

Tags: html, angular

I have a wizard where you step through it, where each step is ngIf'd out with one step active. They all have an ngFor around the same collection.

each item in collection has a div that is hooked for events, where it's the same id on each step but only one step is showing. first step works, 2nd tab does not. The html.id is the same between first step and 2nd div. when we go to 2nd step, 1st step is ngIf'd out of the way.

I have this html

```
<div *ngIf="currentTabId === 'step1'" class="step3-container">
    <div>
        <div class="line-assignment-btn" *ngFor="let button of selectedLineAssignments">
            <app-state-button [id]="button.id"> </app-state-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="currentTabId === 'step2'">
    <div class="line-assignment-btn" *ngFor="let button of selectedLineAssignments">
        <app-state-button [id]="button.id"> </app-state-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am hooking the app-state-button (angular component, using this code in ngInit)

```
const htmlElement = document.getElementById(idUniqueInNgIfButDuplicatedAcrossFalseNgFif)\

htmlElement.addEventListener('touchstart', e => this.onTouchStart(e), true);
      htmlElement.addEventListener('touchend', e => this.onTouchEnd(e), true);
      htmlElement.addEventListener('mousedown', e => this.onMouseDown(e));
      htmlElement.addEventListener('mouseup', e => this.onMouseUp(e));
```

It is the same selectedLineAssignment collection with the same items. I find the first step works the 2nd step doesn't.  If I change the Id's of the items between steps it works. I suspect that I need to unhook when the div is ngIf'd out, but if it's out of view, i'm not sure how'd it get clicks.

So why do i need unique ids as i move between steps?

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: here is stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-95jpbf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html that in itself is illuminating.  I always though ngIf would remove the element from the dom. Here i can see it is hooking the first element found, multiple times. now, what to do about it.